# how to search through sub folders vb.net with a windows service?

Tags: vb.net, windows-services

I'm having problems with my code, the idea is to find a file in a folder but this is a remote folder and it has many sub folders if it doesn't find it then it should look for it in another folder, but it doesn't seem to work could anyone help me please? thanks for any help :).

```
Dim dt2 As New System.Data.DataTable()
        Dim query2 As String = "SELECT juzgado, rutaPDF FROM mismoCorreo WHERE DATEPART(DAY, BirthDate) = @Day AND DATEPART(MONTH, BirthDate) = @Month"
        Dim constr2 As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("constr").ConnectionString
        Using con As New SqlConnection(constr2)
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand(query2)
                cmd.Connection = con
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Day", DateTime.Today.Day)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Month", DateTime.Today.Month)
                Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                    sda.Fill(dt2)
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
        For Each row As DataRow In dt2.Rows
            Dim juzgado As String = row("juzgado").ToString()
            Dim nombre_archivo As String = row("rutaPDF").ToString()

            If (juzgado = "PRIMERO DE LO FAMILIAR") Then

                enviar = "\\172.16.20.101\SisInt\Juzgados\acuerdos\J92016SEM2" & "\" & nombre_archivo & ".docx"


            ElseIf (juzgado = "SEGUNDO DE LO FAMILIAR") Then

                enviar = "\\172.16.20.101\SisInt\Juzgados\acuerdos\J102016SEM2" & "\" & nombre_archivo & ".docx"
            End If

        Next


        For index = 0 To ListaArchivos.Count - 1

            Dim wordApplication = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application()
            Dim wordDocument As Document = Nothing

            Dim paramSourceDocPath As String = ListaArchivos.Item(index)

            Dim paramExportFilePath As String = "\\172.16.20.101\SisInt\Convertidos" + "\" + ListaNombres.Item(index) + ".pdf"
            Dim paramExportFormat As WdExportFormat =
            WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF
            Dim paramOpenAfterExport As Boolean = False
            Dim paramExportOptimizeFor As WdExportOptimizeFor =
            WdExportOptimizeFor.wdExportOptimizeForPrint
            Dim paramExportRange As WdExportRange =
            WdExportRange.wdExportAllDocument
            Dim paramStartPage As Int32 = 0
            Dim paramEndPage As Int32 = 0
            Dim paramExportItem As WdExportItem =
            WdExportItem.wdExportDocumentContent
            Dim paramIncludeDocProps As Boolean = True
            Dim paramKeepIRM As Boolean = True
            Dim paramCreateBookmarks As WdExportCreateBookmarks =
            WdExportCreateBookmarks.wdExportCreateWordBookmarks
            Dim paramDocStructureTags As Boolean = True
            Dim paramBitmapMissingFonts As Boolean = True
            Dim paramUseISO19005_1 As Boolean = False

            Try
                'Abrir documento basados en el que selecciono
                wordDocument = wordApplication.Documents.Open(paramSourceDocPath)

                ' Exportar al formato deseado
                If Not wordDocument Is Nothing Then
                    wordDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat(paramExportFilePath,
                    paramExportFormat, paramOpenAfterExport,
                    paramExportOptimizeFor, paramExportRange, paramStartPage,
                    paramEndPage, paramExportItem, paramIncludeDocProps,
                    paramKeepIRM, paramCreateBookmarks,
                    paramDocStructureTags, paramBitmapMissingFonts,
                    paramUseISO19005_1)
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                'MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
                'Registro en base de datos fecha hora y ex.message 
            Finally

                If Not wordDocument Is Nothing Then
                    wordDocument.Close(False)
                    wordDocument = Nothing
                End If


                If Not wordApplication Is Nothing Then
                    wordApplication.Quit()
                    wordApplication = Nothing
                End If

                GC.Collect()
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
                GC.Collect()
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()

            End Try

        Next
```

Comment: That's a lot of code, which to me is fairly unclear, but from the title, it sounds like you are looking for something like this: `Directory.GetFiles("Filepath", "document.pdf", SearchOption.AllDirectories)`

Comment: excuse me do you know how can i select a specific file? to convert it, the one that i have in my code doesn't seem to work, thank you